# scikit-learn classifer that can handle NaN in data?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, nan

Is there any scikit-learn classifer that can handle NaN in data?

p.s. I know about [sklearn.preprocessing.Imputer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.Imputer.html).

Comment: Can't you modify data to transform NaNs to 0s ? or will that affect the learning phase ? which classifier are you actually using ?

Answer (score -3):

No, why would you ever want to feed a model a NaN? What would you expect the model to do? NaNs have no meaning. All math with NaN just propagates more NaN, it would end up being a horrible mess.

The best you could do is treat it as a missing value and impute it, as you have referenced.

Comment: Well, it is far from being true. NaN should be treated as lack of value, and there are classifiers capable of dealing with missing values much better than through imputation (which is not statistically sound method). For example - decision trees/random forest can deal perfectly with missing values, unfortunately, not scikit-learn implementations

Comment: Treating NaN as a missing value is not the same as a modeling "handling" NaNs. NaNs can not be handled by a model because they have no meaning. Some models support missing values, but NaN does not *mean* missing. It may be used as a place-holder for missing, but it is a completely different thing. If you wrote code to normalize by variance, but you had a feature that was always the same, you get NaN. That doesn't mean its missing. 

And in scikit learn, as I stated, the best you could do with a NaN is to treat it as missing and impute it -since that is all scikit learn supports.

Comment: I treat NaN like missing, and I don't won't to impute it, but want classifier work with it in more natural way as @lejlot says.

Comment: There is no "more natural" way to handle NaNs because they are not natural. NaNs are "Not a Number", they don't exist in real math. They are a construct we created so that we can give a return value to weird things like dividing by zero. 

Why you have NaNs in your data is the bigger question, and what you *should* be focusing on.

Comment: It would be pretty handy to have sklearn just return nans whenever nans were encountered - leave the interpretation up to the user.